# onAttach callback from fragment to activity

Tags: android

I want to send `String` data from `fragment` to `activity`.

I have read the article about communicating between fragment and activity in android developer, using `onAttach` callback.

can anyone explain clearly how to send data from fragment to activity?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should do something like this. First create an interface which will use to comunicate with your activity for example :

```
public interface OnViewSelected {
public void onViewSelected(int viewId);
}
```

and in your `onAttach` do this :

```
OnViewSelected _mClickListener;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        _mClickListener = (OnViewSelected) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement onViewSelected");
    }
}
```

In your Fragment implement `OnClickListener` and in your `onClick()` method do this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    _mClickListener.onViewSelected(456);
}
```

After that in your Activity you have to implement the interface you created in your Fragment and it will ask you to add unimplemented methods and in your activity you will have function like this :

```
@Override
public void onViewSelected(int data) {
    Log.d("","data : "+data); // this value will be 456.
}
```

That's all. : )

Comment: nice :) Android Framework generates like as you say. And I now can understand it clearly

Comment: why to create an interface ? Can't you just create a context ctx (global) , and cast it the activity passed inside onAttach by ctx = (YourActivity) activity, and then use ctx.onViewSelected(data), given ofCourse you have created onViewSelected in your Activity.

Comment: Because in my opinion this is the best way so far,doesn't matter if I use this in one `Fragment` or lots of. Your implementation will work too, but I like interfaces more :)

Comment: @tony9099 the reason for creating the interface (and why the android tutorials explain it that way) is to ensure that your fragment is re-usable and therefore do not depend on that specific Activity but rather a component that implement that listener.

Comment: as of now `public void onAttach(Activity activity)` is officially deprecated.

Comment: @bluebrain so you can use `public void onAttach(Context context)`.

Comment: Question - is it does not provide memory leak? Or should I in onDetach release the callback?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko you can release the callback just in case.