# Android add button to action bar within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

Within my Fragment I need to add refresh button to my actionbar if network is unreacheble.

For example:

```
    private void beginRetriveData() {

            final StringBuilder Request = "some_url_here"

            if(!isNetworkAvailable()) {     

                Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "No active internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
// I NEED TO ADD REFRESH BUTTON TO ACTIONBAR    

            } else {
                     //AsyncTasc here

            }   
        }
```

Which is the best way to do that ?

I tried the following:

```
public MenuItem mRefreshMenuItem;

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        mRefreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_refresh);
        mRefreshMenuItem.setVisible(false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkUnavailable()
    {
        mRefreshMenuItem.setVisible(true); //ERROR HERE 
    }
```

Then in Fragment I called:

```
 if(getActivity() instanceof FragmentsHolderActivity){
      FragmentsHolderActivity myactivity = (FragmentsHolderActivity) activity;
      myactivity.onNetworkUnavailable();
 }
```

but when I call onNetworkUnavailable(),there was a NullPointerException .

Comment: Create a callback to your activity, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213947/onattach-callback-from-fragment-to-activity

Answer (score 3):

Override onCreateOptionsMenu() in your Activity and add a  refresh MenuItem to the Menu (you can do this by inflating a menu resource or instantiating programmatically). Then make the refresh item invisible and save it as an instance variable to access later.

Add to your Activity:

```
private MenuItem mRefreshMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // add your refresh button to res/menu/main.xml
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    mRefreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
    mRefreshMenuItem.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}
```

Next, add an interface so your Fragment can let your Activity know when the network error occurs as described in [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Add to your Fragment:

```
private OnNetworkUnavailableListener mListener;

public interface OnNetworkUnavailableListener
{
    public void onNetworkUnavailable();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        mListener = (OnNetworkUnavailableListener)activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException ex)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " must implement OnNetworkUnavailableListener");
    }
}
```

Additionally, call the method on your interface when the network is unavailable:

```
private void beginRetriveData()
{
    ...
    if(!isNetworkAvailable())
    {     
        mListener.onNetworkUnavailable();
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, implement your interface in the Activity and set the MenuItem's visibility to visible when the network error occurs. Remember to add the "implements OnNetworkUnavailableListener" to your Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnNetworkUnavailableListener
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onNetworkUnavailable()
    {
        mRefreshMenuItem.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But not work. Error (NullPointerException) occurred when I call mListener.onNetworkUnavailable() on line with mRefreshMenuItem.setVisible(true);

Comment: In your updated example, you may be calling onNetworkUnavailable() before onCreateOptionsMenu() is called. When are you calling onNetworkUnavailable()?

Comment: @onCreateOptionsMenu, You are right, onCreateOptionsMenu called after oncreate(), and my fragment called in oncreate. So my trouble is call fragment after onCreateOptionsMenu. But I dont know how.

Comment: Try calling it in onStart() instead of onCreate().