# Start fragment activity

Tags: android

I have an application with many fragments, and am trying to go from one fragment to another when a button is clicked.

The part I'm having trouble with is `startActivity(new Intent(HomeFragment.this, FindPeopleFragment.class));`

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {
}

ImageButton bSearchByLocation, bSearchByNumber;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View InputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
            container, false);

    bSearchByNumber = ((ImageButton) InputFragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.bSearchByLocation));
    bSearchByLocation = ((ImageButton) InputFragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.bSearchByNumber));

    bSearchByLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.bSearchByNumber) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                 startActivity(new Intent(HomeFragment.this, FindPeopleFragment.class));
            }
        }
    });
    bSearchByNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.bSearchByLocation) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    return InputFragmentView;
}
}
```

after i do the solution the code look like this :

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {
}

ImageButton bSearchByLocation, bSearchByNumber;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View InputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
            container, false);

    bSearchByNumber = ((ImageButton) InputFragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.bSearchByLocation));
    bSearchByLocation = ((ImageButton) InputFragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.bSearchByNumber));

    bSearchByLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.bSearchByNumber) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FindPeopleFragment.class));
            }
        }
    });
    bSearchByNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.bSearchByLocation) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    return InputFragmentView;
}
}
```

but when i Run it , the application crash and closed.
this is my androidmanifest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.FindPeopleFragment"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my logchat:
[image]

by the way .... i use this surce code and work on it :
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Fragment`, you should get the hosting activity (the context) as `getActivity()`. Try this instead:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FindPeopleFragment.class));
```

Declare the `FindPeopleFragment` class in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.packagename.FindPeopleFragment" />
```

All `Activities` (not `Fragment`) must to be declare in your manifest file.

Also, check if `FindPeopleFragment` extends `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`. If this extends `Fragment`, don't do an `Intent`. You must to make a `FragmentTransaction` to replace (or add above) your old Fragment (HomeFragment).

---

**UPDATE**

You are wrong in the way to achieve this. You try to start a new `Activity` which, in your case, is a `Fragment` and **not an activity** *(extends Fragment)*. To achieve this, you can:

```
// call a method when click event
((MyFragmentActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragments();
```

Then, inside your `FragmentActivity`, set the method as:

```
// replace the fragment container with this method
public void replaceFragments() {
    Fragment newFragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

---

**UPDATE2**

As *@Squonk* said in comment and also in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571952/2668136), my answer above is a solution but not the right one. To have **a really proper solution**, you need to declare a `Callback interface` and associate the `Fragment` with any `Activity`.

First declare an interface and attach it to your activity in your fragment:

```
OnFragSelected mCallback;

public interface OnFragSelected {
    public void OnFragSelected(int id);
}  

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnFragSelected) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implement OnFragSelected interface..");
    }
}
```

Then call this in your on click event:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mCallback.OnFragSelected(800);
}
```

Finally, in your fragment activity:

```
... implements HomeFragment.OnFragSelected {

    Fragment newFragment;

    @Override
    public void OnFragSelected(int id) {
        // example: id = 800
        // ...
        newFragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

This way *"is more flexible [...] Multiple activities can now embed your Fragment, they just have to implement the communication interface"*. This is important because *"your fragment is re-usable and therefore **do not depend on that specific Activity**"*. Also, if you *"use the fragment elsewhere, you eradicate the risk of a `RuntimeException` because it is strongly typed."*

This question and these answers about [Fragment 2 fragment communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22565661/2668136) can show you the difference. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), you have the google example and this answer: [onAttach callback from fragment to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214076/2668136) might you to figure it out.

Comment: its look fine with code ... but when i start the application and clicked the button , the application crash :( 
@Fllo

Comment: Edit your question and post errors and the LogCat that you have.

Comment: what i do now please
@Fllo

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha "com.yourpackagename" means "info.androidhive.slidingmenu" in your case ;)

Comment: this is the FindPeople fragment :"public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment { "
and i added the logchat you can see it

Comment: When you read your LogCat you see this: "Unable to find explicit activity class [...] have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" - It means that you have not declare the good activity, you have not declare this in manifest or (in your case) you're trying to start a Fragment with a start Activity method. I will edit my answer to make this behaviour with Fragment and not Activity.

Comment: @Fllo : Although the OP has accepted your answer, this is not a good way for a `Fragment` to communicate with its parent `Activity`. In your "UPDATE" example code it relies on the `Fragment` being attached to a parent `MyFragmentActivity` - this will prevent the `Fragment` being used with any other type of `Activity` without having to rewrite the code. Instead a `Fragment` should declare a callback interface and any `Activity` which uses that `Fragment` should implement the interface. In this way the `Fragment` never needs to know what kind of `Activity` it is attached to.

Comment: @Squonk You have right! I updated my answer to show the proper way to achieve that. Feel free to edit it. Thanks.

Comment: hello @Fllo .... i Can't Understand Where should i put this three code that you updated

Comment: Hi @RabeeaQabaha, you should see the 3 links at the end of my answer, espacially the google example (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). You'll see that the first two codes are in Fragment and the on click call the 3rd one in your FragmentActivity. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do this to your intent :

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), FindPeopleFragment.class));
```

and add this to your manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.yourpackagename.FindPeopleFragment"></activity>
</application>
```

Add your activity to your manifest inside the applications tag.

It should work now .. :)

Comment: its look fine with code ... but when i start the application and clicked the button , the application crash :(

Comment: is your other activity registered in your manifest ? if yes, then please post your log.

Comment: i don't know if it registered or not , i post the manifest code above

Comment: not work yet , i edit the question and update it
@mike20132013

Comment: The error is saying that your activity is not declared in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment` should be modular, self-contained and reusable - it shouldn't know about other application components.

Don't start an `Activity` directly from a `Fragment`. Instead you should declare an interface which your parent `Activity` implements. When you click a button in your `Fragment` it should make a call to a method in the interface telling the parent `Activity` which button has been pressed. The parent `Activity` can then start which ever `Activity` is needed.

See [Creating Event Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha : I've edited my answer to show a link which explains how to add an interface as a callback to the `Activity`.