# Use onClick Listener for a button located in one of tab fragment, in Main Activity?

Tags: android

Can I use `onClick` Listener for a button located in one of tab fragment, in Main Activity?

Comment: If you use the `onClick` attribute in a layout inflated from XML, the value provided will always reference a method in the associated `Activity` and not the `Fragment`. It's a bit of an iffy design, but it'll actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to perform some action in your MAIN ACTIVITY when a button is clicked in your fragment. If I am right, then just create a interface callback from your fragment to the activity and use the over-ridden method to perform whatever action you require.

Have a look at this

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

or this

[onAttach callback from fragment to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213947/onattach-callback-from-fragment-to-activity)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i want to call notifications,because i cant call them from my fragment call or can I??example please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can think of a `Fragment` as a stand alone user interface that contains it's own animations and logic. So an `onClickListener` for a `Button` in a `Fragment` is no different than in an `Activity`.

Comment: but my app crashes when I call the set on click listener in main activity, i works only when i call in fragment tab class

Comment: Well without seeing the error, I'm guessing its because your Main Activity doesn't "see" the button, so of course you'll get an error. If you want to call a method in your Main Activity from a button in your Fragment, you'll to set put an interface in your Fragment that your Main Activity will implement - see more here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

Though the method using Interface is sufficient, this is the simple way to do it.

1. You can pass context("getActivity()") of MainActivity while calling
   the fragment.

   2. Create a method in MainActivity to change the fragment.
   3. call the MainActivity method to set the Fragment.

   ((MainActivity) context).setFragment(fragment);

you are done.